# Determinant of $n$-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematics, volume

Consider a Schwarzschild like metric

\begin{equation}
ds^2= -f(r)dt^2 +f(r)^{-1}dr^2 +r^2 d\Omega^2_{d-2}.
\end{equation}

Now consider an induced metric at the boundary given by $ds_{bdy}^2 = r^2 d \Omega^2_{d-2}$. I am interested at the area of this boundary. So I will integrate over all d-2 angular directions for a fixed $r$.

The area is given by

\begin{equation}
A \sim \int{dx^{d-2} \sqrt{h}}
\end{equation}

where $h$ is the determinant of the metric from $ds^2_{bdy}$.

My question is how to actually compute the determinant of this general (d-2)-sphere?

For a 1-d sphere the induced metric is just $ds^2 = r^2 \theta^2$ so we would get $h=r^2$ and $0<\theta \leq 2 \pi$. So,
\begin{equation}
A\sim \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta r = 2 \pi r
\end{equation}
But I am not sure how to generalize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically asking "what is the surface area of an *n*-sphere?"  As noted in the Wikipedia article on the [*n*-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area), the surface area is
$$
S_n = \frac{2 \pi^{(n+1)/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} r^n
$$
where $r$ is the value of the areal coordinate on the sphere under consideration.  (In fact, this is typically how the "radial" coordinate $r$ is defined in the context of a higher-dimensional curved spacetime:  so that the "surface area" of the orbits of the $O(n)$ action is equal to $S_{n-1}$.)